# Kotlin Coroutines: Make a thread executing a code while the other waiting the first to complete

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have find the following code from https://github.com/blink22/react-native-html-to-pdf/blob/master/android/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java converted in Kotlin:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor
import android.print.PrintAttributes.Resolution
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback
import android.util.Log
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import java.io.File


/**
 * Converts HTML to PDF.
 *
 *
 * Can convert only one task at a time, any requests to do more conversions before
 * ending the current task are ignored.
 */
class PdfConverter private constructor() : Runnable {
    private var mContext: Context? = null
    private var mHtmlString: String? = null
    private var mPdfFile: File? = null
    private var mPdfPrintAttrs: PrintAttributes? = null
    private var mIsCurrentlyConverting = false
    private var mWebView: WebView? = null
    private var done: Boolean = false

    override fun run() {
        mWebView = WebView(mContext as Context)
        mWebView!!.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) throw RuntimeException(
                    "call requires API level 19"
                ) else {
                    val documentAdapter =
                        mWebView!!.createPrintDocumentAdapter()
                    documentAdapter.onLayout(
                        null,
                        pdfPrintAttrs,
                        null,
                        object : LayoutResultCallback() {},
                        null
                    )
                    documentAdapter.onWrite(
                        arrayOf(PageRange.ALL_PAGES),
                        outputFileDescriptor,
                        null,
                        object : WriteResultCallback() {
                            override fun onWriteFinished(pages: Array<PageRange>) {
                                destroy()
                                done = true
                            }
                        })

                }
                Log.d("end of onpagefinished()", "end of onpagefinished()")
            }
        }
        mWebView!!.loadData(mHtmlString, "text/HTML", "UTF-8")
        Log.d("end of run()", "end of run()")

    }


    var pdfPrintAttrs: PrintAttributes?
        get() = if (mPdfPrintAttrs != null) mPdfPrintAttrs else defaultPrintAttrs
        set(printAttrs) {
            mPdfPrintAttrs = printAttrs
        }

    fun convert(
        context: Context?,
        htmlString: String?,
        file: File?
    ) {
        requireNotNull(context) { "context can't be null" }
        requireNotNull(htmlString) { "htmlString can't be null" }
        requireNotNull(file) { "file can't be null" }
        if (mIsCurrentlyConverting) return
        mContext = context
        mHtmlString = htmlString
        mPdfFile = file
        mIsCurrentlyConverting = true
        runOnUiThread(this)
        Log.d("end of convert()","end of convert()")
    }

    private val outputFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor?
        private get() {
            try {
                mPdfFile!!.createNewFile()
                Log.d("outputfiledescriptor","the file has been created")
                return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(
                    mPdfFile,
                    ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_TRUNCATE or ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to open ParcelFileDescriptor", e)
            }
            return null
        }

    private val defaultPrintAttrs: PrintAttributes?
        private get() = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) null else PrintAttributes.Builder()
            .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_GOVT_LETTER)
            .setResolution(Resolution("RESOLUTION_ID", "RESOLUTION_ID", 600, 600))
            .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
            .build()

    private fun runOnUiThread(runnable: Runnable) {
        val handler = Handler(mContext!!.mainLooper)
        handler.post(this)
    }

    private fun destroy() {
        mContext = null
        mHtmlString = null
        mPdfFile = null
        mPdfPrintAttrs = null
        mIsCurrentlyConverting = false
        mWebView = null
        Log.d("end of destroy()","end of destroy()")
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "PdfConverter"
        private var sInstance: PdfConverter? = null
        @get:Synchronized
        val instance: PdfConverter?
            get() {
                if (sInstance == null) sInstance =
                    PdfConverter()
                return sInstance
            }
    }
}
```

I want the execution to wait for the `onWriteFinished` before go back to `runOnUiThread`. Also I want the main Thread to execute `run`. So I tried to make it happen with the following code using coroutines :

```
package android.print

import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor
import android.print.PrintAttributes.Resolution
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback
import android.util.Log
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import java.io.File


/**
 * Converts HTML to PDF.
 *
 *
 * Can convert only one task at a time, any requests to do more conversions before
 * ending the current task are ignored.
 */
class PdfConverter2 {
    private var mContext: Context? = null
    private var mHtmlString: String? = null
    private var mPdfFile: File? = null
    private var mPdfPrintAttrs: PrintAttributes? = null
    private var mIsCurrentlyConverting = false
    private var mWebView: WebView? = null
    private var done: Boolean = false

    suspend fun run() {
        Log.d("run()","is this the main thread :"+(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()))
        mWebView = WebView(mContext as Context)
        mWebView!!.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) throw RuntimeException(
                    "call requires API level 19"
                ) else {
                    val documentAdapter =
                        mWebView!!.createPrintDocumentAdapter()
                    documentAdapter.onLayout(
                        null,
                        pdfPrintAttrs,
                        null,
                        object : LayoutResultCallback() {},
                        null
                    )
                    documentAdapter.onWrite(
                        arrayOf(PageRange.ALL_PAGES),
                        outputFileDescriptor,
                        null,
                        object : WriteResultCallback() {
                            override fun onWriteFinished(pages: Array<PageRange>) {
                                destroy()
                                done = true
                            }
                        })

                }
                Log.d("end of onpagefinished()", "end of onpagefinished()")
            }
        }
        mWebView!!.loadData(mHtmlString, "text/HTML", "UTF-8")
        Log.d("end of run()", "end of run()")

    }


    var pdfPrintAttrs: PrintAttributes?
        get() = if (mPdfPrintAttrs != null) mPdfPrintAttrs else defaultPrintAttrs
        set(printAttrs) {
            mPdfPrintAttrs = printAttrs
        }

    fun convert(
        context: Context?,
        htmlString: String?,
        file: File?
    ) {
        requireNotNull(context) { "context can't be null" }
        requireNotNull(htmlString) { "htmlString can't be null" }
        requireNotNull(file) { "file can't be null" }
        if (mIsCurrentlyConverting) return
        mContext = context
        mHtmlString = htmlString
        mPdfFile = file
        mIsCurrentlyConverting = true
        runOnUiThread()
        Log.d("end of convert()","end of convert()")
    }

    private val outputFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor?
        private get() {
            try {
                mPdfFile!!.createNewFile()
                Log.d("outputfiledescriptor","the file has been created")
                return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(
                    mPdfFile,
                    ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_TRUNCATE or ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to open ParcelFileDescriptor", e)
            }
            return null
        }

    private val defaultPrintAttrs: PrintAttributes?
        private get() = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) null else PrintAttributes.Builder()
            .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_GOVT_LETTER)
            .setResolution(Resolution("RESOLUTION_ID", "RESOLUTION_ID", 600, 600))
            .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
            .build()

    private fun runOnUiThread() {
        runBlocking {
            run()
            while(!done){

            }
        }

    }

    private fun destroy() {
        mContext = null
        mHtmlString = null
        mPdfFile = null
        mPdfPrintAttrs = null
        mIsCurrentlyConverting = false
        mWebView = null
        Log.d("end of destroy()","end of destroy()")
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "PdfConverter2"
        private var sInstance: PdfConverter2? = null
        @get:Synchronized
        val instance: PdfConverter2?
            get() {
                if (sInstance == null) sInstance =
                    PdfConverter2()
                return sInstance
            }
    }
}
```

Also there is a function in another file that calls the PdfConverter and it calls the `PdfConverter`.

```
fun createPdfFromHtml(htmlstring: String) {
       val converter: PdfConverter? = PdfConverter.instance
        val file = File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().toString() + "/" + name_of_directory_of_pdfs + "/",
            nameofpdf
        )
        converter?.convert(m_context, htmlstring, file)
        mFilepdf = file
}
```

**What I want is the code execution stops at the 'converter?.convert(m_context, htmlstring, file)' and wait for 'onWriteFinished' of PdfConverter to be executed and then continue. The other senario I thought was that the execution stops at 'runonUiThread' and wait for ''onWriteFinished' again to be executed.**

After the answer of @m0skit0 I change the last code :

```
fun createPdfFromHtml(htmlstring: String) {
        val file = File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path.toString() + "/" + name_of_directory_of_pdfs + "/",
            nameofpdf
        )
        var converter = PdfConverter3.from(m_context)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {// I TRY ALSO Dispatchers.Main
           converter.convert(htmlstring, file)
        }
        mFilepdf = file
        Log.d("mich/createPDfFromHtml", "at the end of createPdfFromHtml, is this the main thread ? "+ (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()))
}
```

But the thing is existing again.

Comment: You can't make UI thread to wait. That will yield an ANR.

Comment: @m0skit0 Maybe I didn't say it clear. I want the UI thread to execute 'run' not to wait. Because it has to do with View...

Comment: A class that does background tasks should never access GUI elements. Why don't you pass a callback to this class and it informs you when it's finished then you do what you want to do in the GUI? A class should have a single responsibility.

Comment: @m0skit0 . Thank you very much. Another one question, just for me to be sure I understood. The 'run' function should not be executed from UI thread due to the fact that it use View components? Because I have read this somewhere I didn't remember where.

Comment: @m0skit0 Looking at the original Java source code, this class internally creates a WebView to use its functionality to create a PDF, and then disposes of the WebView.

Comment: Do not wrap convert() only in a launch. I suggest making createPdfFromHtml() a suspend function as well, then wrap it in a coroutine when called. Note that you can make convert return a Deferred<File> as well with the deferred job if you prefer. It's hard to advise you when we don't know how your app is structured though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on translating that class to Kotlin using coroutines

```
package org.m0skit0.android.testapp

import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.content.Context
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor
import android.print.PageRange
import android.print.PrintAttributes
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import java.io.File
import kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.resumeWithException
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

@TargetApi(19)
class PdfConverter private constructor(private val context: Context) {

    private val defaultPrintAttributes: PrintAttributes by lazy {
        PrintAttributes.Builder()
            .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_GOVT_LETTER)
            .setResolution(PrintAttributes.Resolution("RESOLUTION_ID", "RESOLUTION_ID", 600, 600))
            .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
            .build()
    }

    private var printAttributes: PrintAttributes? = null

    fun printAttributes(printAttributes: PrintAttributes): PdfConverter = apply {
        this.printAttributes = printAttributes
    }

    suspend fun convert(htmlString: String, pdfFile: File) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            suspendCoroutine<Unit> { continuation ->
                WebView(context).apply {
                    webViewClient = WebViewClientImpl(pdfFile, continuation)
                }.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun File.outputFileDescriptor(): ParcelFileDescriptor? =
        try {
            createNewFile()
            ParcelFileDescriptor.open(this, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_TRUNCATE or ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }

    companion object {
        fun from(context: Context): PdfConverter = PdfConverter(context)
    }

    private inner class WebViewClientImpl(private val file: File, private val continuation: Continuation<Unit>) : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(webView: WebView, url: String) {
            webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter()?.run {
                onLayout(
                    null,
                    printAttributes ?: defaultPrintAttributes,
                    null,
                    object : PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback() {},
                    null
                )
                onWrite(
                    arrayOf(PageRange.ALL_PAGES),
                    file.outputFileDescriptor(),
                    null,
                    object : PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback() {
                        override fun onWriteCancelled() {
                            super.onWriteCancelled()
                            continuation.resume(Unit)
                        }

                        override fun onWriteFailed(error: CharSequence?) {
                            super.onWriteFailed(error)
                            continuation.resumeWithException(Exception(error.toString()))
                        }

                        override fun onWriteFinished(pages: Array<out PageRange>?) {
                            super.onWriteFinished(pages)
                            continuation.resume(Unit)
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. I will put it in my code and I will reply to you back.

Comment: I tried your solution but the same problem ... The execution returns to the caller of 'PdfConverter' before the 'run' function end its procedure to write on the pdf.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood what you wanted, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I will reply back with the result.

Comment: I made an edit ... the last code you post have the same problem. The execution of code continues without waiting the 'onWriteFinished' to be executed. I put to my code Log.d() in order to check it.

Comment: Hmm, strange. How are you calling the convert() function? The remaining code must be inside the same coroutine.

Comment: I used coroutines. I made edit, at the start I didn't paste the code of the caller of PdfConverter because I thought that the stop of the execution will be at the caller of the previous 'runonUiThread' . But yes with your code I had to paste the caller of 'convert'.

Comment: convert() should suspend any coroutine that executes it, which means any code inside that coroutine will not continue executing until convert() calls on continuation.resume, which is done on WriteResultCallback. Can you specify what do you meanby "the execution of code continues without waiting the 'onWriteFinished' to be executed"? Any code outside the coroutine will of course continue to be executed.

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted ... sorry I didn't know it I expected that there will be a way to do this. I must change my way of do the things in my project.

Comment: If you launch a background job and you expect a result, you need to wait for the job to finish. There's no going around this (unless you have a time machine!). You can show a "processing" message or something like that to the user until the job is finished, for example.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly, you want run to be executed on the main thread. In order to achieve this, instead of making run a `suspend` function, you could let the function `launch` a coroutine with the Dispatchers.Main scope.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and I reply back.

Comment: I tried it but the same... the while loop is an infinity loop. The 'onWriteFinished' is never called for some reason.